# AWS Creating layer from zip file uploaded in s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have uploaded my layer zip file in AWS s3 and I tried to create layer and added the link of zip file from s3 I get error:

```
Failed to create layer version: 1 validation error detected: Value 's3' at 'content.s3Bucket' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length greater than or equal to 3
```

Comment: "added the link of zip file from s3" add where, how? Using AWS console, CloudFormatinon, SDK, CLI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting your file in which is in s3 correctly:

```
 https://s3.amazonaws.com/yourbucket/YourFile.zip
```